# Oozie Java Action (oozie version 4.0.0-cdh5.1.0) - Exception from container-launch

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to execute MapReduce application through Oozie Java action on YARN. When I try to execute the application, its failing in Java action with below error message:

```
Exception from container-launch: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException:
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:511)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:424)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:656)
  at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
  at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:300)
  at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

  Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
```

FYI

1. We have recently upgraded our CDH cluster to CDH 5.1 from CDH 4.7
2. We have recently upgraded Oozie from 3.X to 4.0.0
3. The same application worked absolutely fine in Oozie before upgrade to Oozie 4.0.0 and CDH 5.1
4. The MR application is working absolutely fine when run on command line with below command. But, failing only when run through Oozie Java action

> hadoop jar <<-MyJar->> <<-JobDriver->> <<-inputDir->> <<-outputDir->>